# How to use a french MacBook Pro keyboard with Ubuntu?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, keyboard

I have a **MacBook Pro 13'** (mid-2009) with and french keyboard layout and I want to use this keyboard on **Ubuntu 14.04** in the same way as on **Mac OSX Mavericks**.

For example, when I hit the key "@", another character is printed on the screen.

Does anyone have the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution worked for me :

- In *Paramètres système* or *System Settings*, click on *Saisie de texte* or *Text Entry*.
- *Sources d'entrée à utiliser* or *Input sources to use* has to be *Français* or *French* (and **not** *Français (Apple)*, *Français (Macintosh)*, *French (Apple)*, *French (Macintosh)* or anything else.
- Modify the file **/etc/default/keyboard** to have :

  - XKBMODEL="macintosh"
  - XKBLAYOUT="fr"
  - XKBVARIANT=""
  - XKBOPTIONS=""

All the others lines of this file have to be blank or should be commented (this first column should contain **#**).

- Log in / log out or reboot
- That's all !

Comment: Did you mean Systemsteuerung?